# How to detect change in query params in Angular when done via Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I am apending query params in my ASP.NET core app via javascript as below to append it without a reload.
Also I have loaded a angular component in my c# code which is

```
window.history.pushState({path: currentURL}, '', currentURL)
<app-root></app-root>
```

I am using activated route in my angular app in constructor to listen the changes as below

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
let paramObject = {...params['keys'], ...params);
console.log(paramsObject)
})
```

I can only detect changes when there is a page reload and not when I use pushState method to append the query params

Is there something missing here.

Comment: Do I understand correctly. You push state not in the angular context. If so, it doesn't matter where you do so. Actually I don't quite understand the term "loaded a angular component in my c#". Are you using peppier or something like that to control the browser from C#?

Comment: In any case. If my first assumption is right. There is no way for the route.queryParams observable to be notified about such thing, because you do it outside of angular context. What you can do is to build a message bus on your window object and emit it when you do what you do with url. Then other listening code on Angular will listen for this bus and read out of context url and push it to the router. 
But, why do you need such ugly way?

Comment: @simplygood So <app-root> is my angular component that loads a chart in my C# cshtml file. Push state is done in javascript and I need angular to keep track of changes and call a method on change of query params. Query params would change based on grid filters.

Comment: Who originally changes the query params in the url?

Comment: It is changed in cshtml using Javascript pushstate method and as angular is listening to query param change as I have subscribed it it should detect the changes right?

Comment: No it should not. Query params do not have any sort of change notification. Angular listens not for a Query params change, it listens the internal Angular event which is fired when angular Router navigation happens. When you do most of the things ourside of your angular app it is not catched by it

Comment: So you need to implement any kind of a bus (observable, or simple callback) on you window and listen it in your Angular and when this happens call `router.navigate(copyOfThePath)`.

Comment: But it is not clear to me why it is done like that. Why can't you return 'redirect' code from you backed with the proper url?

Comment: @simplygood I am adding some filters and dont want a reload everytime

Comment: to add some filters without a reloading you can use `this.router.navigate([], {
            relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
            queryParams: urlParams,
            replaceUrl: true, //if you don't want to push to the story
        });`